# Android Studio can't upload the project in Github

Tags: android, git, version-control

I am having a problem when I am trying upload my project from Android Studio. The error message is this.

```
The following problems have occurred when adding the files:
fatal: Unable to create '   
C:/Users/Theo/AndroidStudioProjects/.git/index.lock': File exists.
```

From the solutions I found, people suggest that the index.lock file must be deleted.

```
cd .git
del index.lock
```

But is it safe to delete the index.lock file? Will this action cause any problem for new projects that will be uploaded to git? Just asking.

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: Go ahead and delete it.

Comment: thanks. Problem fixed:)